# How to add objects dynamically to a view pager of CardViews?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgrsCOLM0LA&feature=youtu.be). I looked around and I reached a code similar to this

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<SomeObject> someObjectList;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SomeObject> someObjectList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.someObjectList = someObjectList;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return someObjectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemvView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        SomeObject object = someObjectList.get(position);

        TextView tvTitle = itemvView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tvTitle.setText(object.getTitle());

        ImageView image = itemvView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageResource(object.getImageResource());

        container.addView(itemvView);

        return itemvView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    public void addItems(List<SomeObject> someObject) {
        // TODO : Add objects dynamically without using notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

I also modified a custom View Pager component to match my needs

**Custom View Pager**

```
class VerticalViewPager : ViewPager {

    private val MIN_SCALE = 0.75f

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, VerticalPageTransformer())
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
    }

    private inner class VerticalPageTransformer : ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {

            when {
                position < -1 -> // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                    view.alpha = 0f
                position <= 0 -> { // [-1,0]
                    // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                    view.alpha = 1f
                    // Counteract the default slide transition
                    view.translationX = view.width * -position

                    //set Y position to swipe in from top
                    val yPosition = position * view.height
                    view.translationY = yPosition
                    view.scaleX = 1f
                    view.scaleY = 1f

                }
                position <= 1 -> { // [0,1]
                    view.alpha = 1f

                    // Counteract the default slide transition
                    view.translationX = view.width * -position


                    // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                    val scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position))
                    view.scaleX = scaleFactor
                    view.scaleY = scaleFactor

                }
                else -> // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                    view.alpha = 0f
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private fun swapXY(ev: MotionEvent): MotionEvent {
        val width = width.toFloat()
        val height = height.toFloat()

        val newX = ev.y / height * width
        val newY = ev.x / width * height

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY)

        return ev
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev))
        swapXY(ev) // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev))
    }
}
```

And I inserted the custom ViewPager view in the main_activity.xml and set the adapter in the MainActivity.java..

I need to add the card items dynamically and infinitely. i.e. The data will be loaded as the user scrolls through the card stack and will show infinite cards.

So for that, I will need to add objects to the view pager dynamically as the cards are scrolled down.

As I googled, the only way to add more data to the view pager is to use the notifyDataSetChanged method. But I do not want this as it becomes really inefficient as the data size increases.'

How do I add more data to the view pager dynamically?

I figured out the way to notify the activity when to load. I just need to figure out how to set the data without using notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Why adding the data dynamically if the problem is memory you could just use Fragment State Pager Adapter.

Comment: But I am not using fragments here. I'm using card views with the pager adapter. Check out the link in the question. That's the effect I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If I were you I would have used fragmentstatepageradapter and a normal view pager and respond to screen gesture to change the current item of view pager. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Comment: Yeah, that I can experiment. But that's not my problem right now.

Comment: If you are trying make the same effect ,then the same app is available in github: https://github.com/llRizvanll/InshortApp you can use this and change according to your need.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it out. But he isn't using variable number of items.